# How to wrap elements in a <td> and then append the td to tr

Tags: jquery, each

I have this code:

```
<tr id="row">
    <td id="col">
        <img>
        text
        <p></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to take each "text" and `<p>` from the tr, wrap them separately in a `<td>` and add them to the main `<tr>`.

The final result shoud look like this:

```
<tr id="row">
    <td id="col"><img></td>
    <td class="text-class">text><td>
    <td class="p-class"><p></p></td>
</tr>
```

I tried to find each element and wrap it in a td but I cannot do it right.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: ('.#col p').wrap('<td class="someclass"></td>'); then I've tried to append it to the tr. without success

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var map = $('#col').replaceWith(function(){
    var map = $(this).contents().map(function(idx){
        var $td = $('<td />');
        if(this.nodeType == 3){
            if($.trim($(this).text()) == ''){
                return
            } else {
                $td.addClass('text-class');
            }
        } else if($(this).is('p')){
            $td.addClass('p-class');
        }

        return $td.append(this)
    });
    map.get(0).attr('id', this.id)
    return map.get()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z7qxW/)

Comment: @Pr3tor which browser?

Answer (score 0):

Work with Javascript:

- to retrieve the `colElement` column, retrieve the code having `id = "col"` (see [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp))
- to read its children of type `p`, do the following: `var p = colElement.getElementsByTagName("p");` (the same applies for all the other types of children - see [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp) for information)

Just iterate on the collections you retrieve in this way, and wrap them in a `<td>` tag by adding them as children of the tag (see [the appendChild method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) for further information).

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($){
    myTD = $("tr#row > td");
    myTD.children().each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        wrapper = $("<td></td>");            
        wrapper
            .addClass($this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase()+"-class")
            .html($this)
            .appendTo(myTD.parent());
    });
    myTD.remove();
});
```

Not exactly what you wanted, but close. You can add logic to add original td id to first element of cycle by modifying .each(function(index){ and so on...